# My class conforms to ObservableObject but somehow swift compiler does not think so

Tags: swift

```
protocol ErrorableViewProtocol: View {
    var error: Error? { get set }
}

class ObservableError: ObservableObject {
    @Published var error: Error?
}

struct ErrorableView<T: ErrorableViewProtocol>: View {
    var errorable: T
    
    var body: some View {
        if let error = errorable.error {
            ErrorView(error: error)
        } else {
            errorable
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Where did I stray off the righeous path?

Comment: What are all those optionals for? Many property wrappers don’t like optionals. And a @StateObject is supposed to be initialized

Comment: actually you are right: changing error from optional like so @StateObject var observable_error: ObservableError = ObservableError() fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableError` conforms to `ObservableObject`. You can't say the same about `Optional<ObservableError>` (aka `ObservableError?`). When you use `@StateObject`, you should always instantiate the class in the same struct.

However, when you want to pass in an object from another struct, use `@ObservedObject`.